# How to write APNS FeedBack Service using java?

Tags: java, ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am working on sending Push Notifications to an Apple device using Java. For this i am using JavaPNS-2.1.1 library. I have successfully sent push notifications to an apple device. But when i call APNS FeedBack Service it doesnt return anything.

To test the APNS Feedback Service, i deleted the app first from device then sent few notifications to that device. While sending push notifications i called the FeedBack Service every time i sent push notification. But each time it doesnt return anything. The piece of code for FeedBack Service as below,

```
List<Device> devices = new Vector<Device>();
FeedbackServiceManager feedbackManager = new FeedbackServiceManager();
feedbackManager.setProxy(host,port);
AppleFeedbackServer server = new AppleFeedbackServerBasicImpl(keystore, password, false);
devices.addAll(feedbackManager.getDevices(server));
return devices;
```

Can anyone help me on where am i getting it wrong? On few Questions here in StackOverflow, i read it works in SandBox environment only, is it true? As i am also working on SandBox here.

What is the exact response does the Feedback Service provides? Will it give me all notifications failed? Or only the device token to which it doesnt delivered the notification? Suppose i sent 3 notifications to only one device, then will it give me all 3 instances of failure or device token of that device with timestamp of last failure?

When should i call the FeedBack Service? Means exactly after how much time i call it when APNS fails to deliver push notifications?

Answer (score 1):

My experience with the sandbox-feedback service is that it only works if you have two different sandbox-push enabled apps on your device.  When you uninstall one of them, you'll get something on the feedback service saying the token isn't valid anymore.  This was several years ago when I tested it, so I don't know if it still applies.

Comment: Ok. Its not returning anything for me. Have multiple push notification supported apps on device but i have only one device token to test. Do i need multiple devices to test this thing? Also does it return all notifications failed with timestamp for the device or only the device token with timestamp for last failed attempt?

Comment: I missed a very important point in your answer, two "sandbox push enabled apps" should be there. I was having multiple apps those were live. Also i changed my jar from 2.1.1 to 2.2 and its working fine now. Only thing to worry is its returning deviceTokens on second day.

Comment: I am getting device tokens on same day itself now..!! If anybody faces this problem using JavaPNS, i will suggest to please use 2.2 library and documentation for coding. And when you are testing it in sandbox please make sure you should have another sandbox push enabled app on the phone when you uninstalled your original app.